# Excel Workbook too large for VBA macros?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2010 32-bit and have a workbook that is 120 MB in size. I am programming some vba macros to drive pivot tables and seem to be experiencing some issues related to the size.  I am wondering what some of my options are as upgrading to 64 bit versions are out of the question at this time. Obviously there are other options which I would prefer but my output is limited to excel 2010 at this stage. Can I maybe utilize a separate workbook and pull pivot data that way or would I experience the same issues. I also am thinking about utilizing Access to hold my data and pull that way using Excel as the front end. Which would be the best option?

Here is the basics pivot table creation:

```
Sub MakePivotTable()

Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim cacheOfpt As PivotCache
Dim PF As PivotField
Dim PI As PivotItem

On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Pivot").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Data_Pivot").TableRange2.Clear

Sheets("Data").Select
Set cacheOfpt = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xldatabase, Range("A1:CC300000"))

Sheets("Pivot").Select
Set PT = activesheet.PivotTables.Add(cacheOfpt, Range("A1"), "Data_Pivot")

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the "issues related to the size"?

Comment: System resources. I have tried removing formatting to make the size smaller. The number of rows are about 300k. When trying to generate just the pivot table itself it is stating that excel can not complete the process try choosing fewer rows.

Comment: @Leigh.Granger When you close Excel, open the Task Manager and see if you still have an excel.exe process running. It sounds like Excel did not close properly (perhaps during the execution/testing of your VBA) and this instance of Excel is hogging an inordinate amount of system resources. Excel and VBA can handle content and data at much higher amounts than what you have mentioned thus far.

Comment: @K.Davis I have added the VBA I am using

Comment: @Leigh.Granger On a separate note - the question you're asking above is off-topic as it's soliciting opinion-based ideas from folks; if instead you refocus your question (your recent edit to include code is a great start) to be exclusively about solving the problem with this error, that might make it more on-topic (though there's still a chance it might be more appropriate on Superuser... not sure yet where the issue lies-- in the code-behind or the OS)

Comment: @TylerH Changing the data source to a table seems to have solved the problem with the size. However Using the above code is not generating a Pivot table as expected.

Comment: @Leigh.Granger It is typically encouraged to use a table as a data source for pivot tables for several reasons. If you have that problem solved and now have a different one (e.g. my code doesn't generate a pivot table correctly), I would recommend asking a separate question to avoid crossing any wires with the answerers/helpers here.

Comment: Looks like it’s time to upgrade to 64 bit I’m afraid - you’re asking to much from the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following resolved my issue in the end.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePivotTableAndPivotCache()

    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Sheet1.Name & "!" & Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count

    Worksheets.Add
    Range("A3").Select

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=ActiveCell, _
        TableName:="DataPivot")

    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count
    Debug.Print pc.MemoryUsed, pc.RecordCount, pc.Version

End Sub
```

Comment: Why did it resolve it? What is the key difference (too hard to read a wall of code)?